# I need help on this C# problem: Why does the error: "A get or set accessor expected" come up at compile time?

Tags: c#

[image]
I tried to fix it on youtube and it didn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Something must be wrong with your intellisense. Your syntax has all sorts of problems, to include not enclosing your class in braces.

Comment: FYI in the future, please use actual text for code, not an image

Answer (score 2):

Move line 8 up to line 6. It should look like:

```
public class move : MonoBehaviour {
    public float dichuyen;
    public float tocdo;
    void Start() {}
    ..
```